# Execution failed for task ':buildDB2BotcImage'

Tags: docker, gradle, build.gradle, devops, docker-image

> **System Info :** Windows 10 Enterprise
>
> **Gradle Version** 4.3.1
>
> **Docker Version**  17.10.0-ce, build f4ffd25

I am getting an issue while doing gradle.build, Error I am getting

```
Unrecognized field "identitytoken" (class com.github.dockerjava.api.model.AuthConfig), not marked as ignorable (6 known properties: "serveraddress", "username", "auth", "password", "email", "registrytoken"])
   at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: java.util.LinkedHashMap["auths"]->java.util.LinkedHashMap["registry.au-syd.bluemix.net"]->com.github.dockerjava.api.model.AuthConfig["identitytoken"])
```

I have done some research and found this https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-docker-plugin/issues/310 , and done some changes in my build.gradle but still i am getting this error.

The changes I have done in one of the part of build.gradle file :

**Previously:**

```
docker {
    if (System.properties['os.name'].toLowerCase().contains('windows')) {
        url = 'tcp://localhost:2376'
        certPath = new File(System.properties['user.home'], '.docker/machine/certs')
    }
    registryCredentials {
        url = 'https://maxrep01.swg.usma.ibm.com/'
        username = 'username'
        password = 'secret'
    }
}
```

**Changed:**

```
docker {
    if (System.properties['os.name'].toLowerCase().contains('windows')) {
         if (new File("\\\\.\\pipe\\docker_engine").exists()) {
           url = 'npipe:////./pipe/docker_engine'
        }
        else {
           url = 'tcp://localhost:2376'
        }
        certPath = new File(System.properties['user.home'], '.docker/machine/certs')
    }
    registryCredentials {
        url = 'https://maxrep01.swg.usma.ibm.com/'
        username = 'username'
        password = 'secret'
    }
}
```

This is the only helpful link I am getting, but I am unable to get what is the issue is, my understanding is it is something related to windows 10, but as per the link the changes i have done should resolve the issue.

I am not sure what is wrong here?

Comment: Any chance you can post the whole build file?

Comment: I did try that, but its way too long to accommodate here.
If you are looking for some specific information i can do that.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is most likely related to [Issue #921](https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java/issues/921) of the [docker-java](https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java) project.

> Hello, we got the issue, using latest version of "docker-java" while trying to load and parse DOCKER configuration file (`"$HOME/.docker/config.json"`).
>
> It doesn't accept the field `'identitytoken'`. I have noticed that you have `'registrytoken'` field, which have been used since [DOCKER API v1.22](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.22/) version for the same purpose. I checked documentation, it was renamed there into --> `'identitytoken'` just in the next [DOCKER API v1.23](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.23/) version.

If waiting for a next [docker-java](https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java) version is not acceptable, it might help to tweak `config.json` to suit your needs.